# Static PHP application directory on a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble setting up a directory with php files on a wordpress site.

I understand how to use templates to include a custom php file, but what I'm trying to do is access a php file as if wordpress was not installed. Right now when I create a new directory(dir1) and put an index.php file in that folder, then try to view by going to www.test.com/dir1  it shows a bulleted list with links to header, background, and updates with a text input for searching the website at the bottom.

I'm not sure if this is something that needs to be configure in my cPanel or if its a wordpress setting, or even if its an htaccess issue.

Please help me figure out what I need to do, or even at the very least, help me put into words what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: So you can not access it directly, i.e. `www.test.com/dir1/index.php`?

Comment: Nope, same thing happens

Comment: BTW this is on a wordpress 1 site. I also have a WP 3 site that if I do the same thing, it just says the links broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, I've figured it out.

anytime I would FTP files onto my server, it would make the owner/group "root"

After I used WinSCP to change my users to match each website, it worked perfectly.

cPanel is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Wordpress installed in the root has no impact at all on whatever is put into non-wp directories. Can you paste your .htaccess file from the root folder? And does your /dir1/ have any .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has nothing do to with existing folders/files. Here are some steps you may try.

1. Make sure your **/dir1 doesn't have .htaccess** or **if in case you have and you need it to have it there, continue doing next steps.**
2. Add some **inclusions in rewrite engine** of your .htaccess file. You may add something like this:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d **and/or** RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

**or**

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !dir1

I hope this helps.